# Glassware Starter Java Edition NotifyServlet never called

Tags: java, subscriptions, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Deployed the java edition of the glassware starter project in GAE. All works fine.
When I subscribe to timeline collection changes and publish a text update using the default starter project UI, the NotifyServlet is not called.
Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You do not receive updates about changes you make to the timeline.

Subscribing to updates to the `timeline` collection triggers a notification when your user causes a chance to a timeline item via an interaction with Glass. If you make the change programmatically via the Mirror API, you will not be notified since it's assumed you already know.

Comment: Thanks. This confirms what we thought. However, I was assuming that the dev tool: Playground would be able to emulate a Google Glass without the need to have the physical glass.

Comment: The Playground only sends "fake" notification when using a custom `menuItem`.